# ERROR : invalid coulmn name Oracle database when using native query in springboot (BETWEEN keyword)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, nativequery

I'm new using native queries and I'm trying to use a native query with "BETWEEN" keyword in oracle DB

here is my query:

```
@Query(value="select * from TABLE_NAME where COLUMN_NAME between ?1 and ?2",nativeQuery=true)
public list<CLASS_NAME> findAllWithinInterval(String fromDate,String toDate)
```

but I got an error that said: "Invalid column name"

NOTE: this SQL query works fine on Oracle developer tool (Oracle database)

Comment: If the COLUMN_NAME is of type DATE in the database you must pass two dates as parameters and not strings.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the column type is String as well.

Comment: Then please show the whole stacktrace.

Comment: Did you try running same query in  Oracle database?

Answer (score 0):

this is a temporary solution but it worked for me

i had to select specific columns that i need to use in my code not all columns in the table, i don't really know yet what's wrong with selecting all columns but this solution may help, i used this query instead:

```
@Query(value="select COLUMN_ONE from TABLE_NAME where COLUMN_NAME between ?1 and ?2",nativeQuery=true)
public list<COLUMN_TYPE> findAllWithinInterval(String fromDate,String toDate)
```